# Storing vectors into a cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, cell-array

I have a 128x100 matrix called R.

I have another 1x100 matrix called I.
Values in vector I range from 1-64.

e.g. I: [13,22,55,63 ... ,35]

There is a one-to-one correspondence between elements of R and I.

I want to know for each unique value of I, i.e. if 1 occurs in six positions (column# 12, 20, 35, 62, 87, 95) in vector I,  how to concatenate the corresponding (column# 12, 20, 35, 62, 87, 95) columns in R and store the info in a single cell array S for all such values from 1-64.

I tried but am not able to think of a compact and correct code.

```
for j = 1:64
   for i = 1:100
       if I(i) == j
           S{j} = R(:,i);
       end      
   end    
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
S = accumarray(I(:),1:100,[64 1],@(x){R(:,x)});
```

If array `I` doesn't contain all values of 1:64 `S` will have empty cells that can be removed this way:

```
S(cellfun(@isempty,S))=[];
```

*Thanks to @LuisMendo for suggestion to improve the answer.

Comment: Very nice use of `accumarray`. If the empty cells are wanted it's better to use `S = accumarray(I(:),1:100,[64 1],@(x){R(:,x)})`, so that empty cells at the end are not trimmed

Comment: Thank you very much. Its a compact code and it works. I need the empty cells too. Thanks again!

Comment: @Alastair_V Answer updated to take into account empty cells at the end.

Comment: Yes. @rahnema1, Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry I got the 'right to mark an answer' just recently. Yes I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This does what tou want:

```
S = arrayfun(@(n) R(:,I==n), 1:64, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Or, with an equivalent loop:

```
S = cell(1,64);
for n = 1:64
  S{n} = R(:,I==n);
end
```

Comment: Thank you. its a compact solution. The equivalent loop also does help.